# Extensive use of SVG in phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, svg

I have a web site that makes extensive use of SVG for scalable maps. After using phonegap ton convert to an app for an android, none of the graphics are rendered correctly or are visible. What is recommended to address this? Should I convert the SVG? Recommend a plug-in...? Would phonegap build handle such a task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and used Cordova and all rendering worked perfectly.